# Model adequacy checking - normal probability plot in R

Tags: r

How can I create a normal probability plot of residuals in R so that there are normal probability values on y-axis?

Comment: run `plot(yourFit)` and cycle through the visuals

Comment: I did it, but what I got is Normal Q-Q with Theoretical Quantiles on x-axis and Residuals on y-axis.

Comment: is that not what you wanted?

Comment: No, I want Residuals on x-axis and Probability on y-axis.

Comment: so, you just want that plot, but transposed...

Comment: How? Quantiles are not probabilities.

Comment: if you know the quantiles, just use `pnorm` to get probs

Comment: Ok, I know that, but my question was if I could create a plot such that I have probability on x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you'll make the normal probability plot with *qqnorm* and *qqline*.

Example:

```
fit <- lm(resp ~ dep1 + dep2)
qqnorm(fit$residuals, datax=TRUE)
qqline(fit$residuals, datax=TRUE)
```

You can get residuals vs. prob. with the *plot* and *pnorm*:

```
plot(fit$residuals, pnorm(fit$residuals))
```

(with prob. on the y-axis)

Comment: Here I got a message **Error in min(x, na.rm = na.rm) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument**

Comment: Sorry. It's fixed now.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wan't this plot, but you can of course do it. I have included the code in the answer above.